# Switching a M.2 NVMe card from ahci (SATA) driver to nvme driver on Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sata, nvme

On a very old laptop (HP 9470m), I have a M.2 NVMe card (WD Blue™ SN550 NVMe™ SS) passing through a NVMe -> SATA converter card to connect to the laptop, as the laptop has no NVMe support.  With a Ubuntu Live disk, longtime ago I formatted the drive and the NVMe was seen by the laptop and Linux as a SATA drive.  All is good and it worked very well; never had an issue with it for years.

Now, I decided to move my M.2 NVMe card from the old laptop to a newer laptop (Dell E7470) that supports NVMe.

So I remove the NVMe card from the SATA converter and put into the new laptop (Dell E7470).  It works!  It boots and runs flawlessly... except it is very slow.

That is because the drive is still configured to be a SATA drive on the new laptop.  It still shows up as (notice the ahci driver in the path):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Fév 12 09:39 /sys/bus/pci/drivers/ahci/0000:00:17.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:17.0
```

I have a 2nd new laptop (Dell E7470) with the same NVME card model but I formatted it on the new laptop too.  Ubuntu configured it as follow (notice the nvme driver in the path):

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 févr. 12 10:15 /sys/bus/pci/drivers/nvme/0000:02:00.0 -> ../../../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/0000:02:00.0
```

This one runs fast!

Is there a way for me, without reformatting the whole drive, to instruct Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to reboot and reassign the NVME card to the nvme driver?

Answer (score 0):

Check your BIOS. Linux works with devices BIOS provides.